# Can your school watch the files that you print on the schools printer, if you use your own laptop to do so ?

Tags: printer

I am just asking out of curiosity

Answer (score 1):

As your school controls the printer and the network, they can do whatever they
want.

It's just a matter of them allocating necessary resources for getting the right
software or for hiring the right programmer.

However, schools don't usually have too many resources ...

Comment: In other words, they can, but if you don't raise flags you'll probably sneak under the radar. However, if there's been a spate of 'printing porn' or 'printing 500-page documents' they may well be watching who is doing it. YMMV.